# RSA: Derive modulus from known ciphertexts encoded with same keypairs

Tags: rsa

I have two ciphertexts

$c_1 = m_1^e \bmod n$

$c_2 = m_2^e \bmod n$

I know $c_1, c_2, m_1, m_2$ and $e$. Is there a way to derive n from this? I first thought Franklin Reiter but I'd need an $n$ for that which is precisely what I am missing. What other approaches are there?

Comment: Hint: $$a\equiv b\pmod m\iff \exists k\in\mathbb Z:a=b+k\cdot m$$

Comment: So from this I derive: $m_1^e + m_2^e - c_1 - c_2 = (j+k) * n$

Comment: But this doesn't help for $e=65537$

Comment: Is this homework?  I ask because if you're learning, I'd attempt to give you a hint; if you're just trying to solve the problem (while learning as little as possible), I'll just give you the answer

Comment: @poncho I'd rather get a hint and if all else fails the answer :) it's not homework but I still want to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the hint you requested:

- We know that we have $m_1^e - c_1 = k_1n$ for some integer $k_1$
- We know that we have $m_2^e - c_2 = k_2n$ for some integer $k_2$

So, given that we know the values $k_1n$ and $k_2n$, how can we recover the common $n$ value?  Hint: look at the $\gcd$ function...

Comment: Worked, had to use sage though

Comment: With that kind of hint, who needs a solution?